# React categories.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I want to render an array to react console, but I get the following error :

```
TypeError: products.map is not a function
```

This is my App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    categories: []
  } 

  renderCategory =  ({category_id, name}) => <div key={category_id}>{name}</div>

  render() {

    const categories = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {categories.map(this.renderCategory)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

After i run : `npm start` in console I got no errors in compilation !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destructuring is incorrect. Update to :

```
const { categories } = this.state;
```

Comment: Works fine. Thanks a lot @Easwar